# Update entity from appengine .GetAll and save to datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model:

```
type UserProfile struct {
UserID         string    `datastore:"user_id" json:"user_id,omitempty"`
Username       string    `datastore:"username" json:"username,omitempty"`
StripUsername  string    `datastore:"strip_username" json:"strip_username,omitempty"`
Email          string    `datastore:"email" json:"email,omitempty"`
LoginType      string    `datastore:"login_type" json:"login_type,omitempty"`
CurrentSession string    `datastore:"current_session" json:"current_session,omitempty"`
FBAcessToken   string    `datastore:"fb_access_token" json:"fb_access_token,omitempty"`
Created        time.Time `datastore:"created" json:"-"`
}
```

And I perform a .GetAll to populate it:

```
// Skip a few steps here

var userProfiles []UserProfile
q.GetAll(c, &userProfiles)
```

Say I want to modify one of those entities:

```
userProfile[0].Email = "test@example.com"
```

I know I want to Put that entity like so:

```
k = datastore.Put(c, k, userProfile[0])
```

How do I get that initial key from userProfile[0] to call Put with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetAll](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Query.GetAll) returns the keys:

```
var userProfiles []UserProfile
keys, err := q.GetAll(c, &userProfiles)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Update entities using the keys returned from GetAll:

```
userProfile[0].Email = "test@example.com"
_, err = datastore.Put(c, keys[0], userProfile[0])
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```